# CSS Not Recognizing "Avenir Next" as my font family

Tags: html, css

I am using CSS for my headers where all menus should be coming as "Avenir Next" font-family. But it is not recognizing it. It is showing as simple Arial.

My code is :

```
#main .Header .mainnav ul {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  margin: -17px 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Avenir Next !important;
  font-size: 14px; 
}
```

Comment: 1) try with enclosing quotes: `"Avenir Next"`; 2) Be sure your font is correctly loaded (check the `net` panel)

Comment: Still, it is not working. I just added a " " and reloaded my page. Still showing as Arial

Comment: Is your font loaded properly?

Comment: Please show how you imported the font in the CSS

Comment: A few things: does your system have a font with that name? If not, do you try to load it? If not, why? If yes, does it work (the loading)?

Comment: Make sure you do the above and also ensure you don't have any local browser settings overriding any fonts (EG. ChromeEdit customisations)

Comment: sorry, at this moment this question *"lacks of minimal information to diagnose the problem"*

Comment: No, My computer doesn't have. I am making it for client. it is not necessary, users who will access my site, should have Avenir Next font. Then what is solution, other than i must have Avenir next on my local.

Comment: @user3095179 If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 20):

Try:

```
#main .Header .mainnav ul {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    margin: -17px 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Avenir Next" !important;
    font-size: 14px; 
}
```

It is because of `" "` Space in font name.

By Looking at your last comment, I'll suggest you to host a `font-file` in either a `.ttf`, `.ote` or `.otf` format and link that file in your page.

and use this code:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Avenir Next';
  src: url("http://www.yoursite.com/fonts/Avenir_Next.otf"); /* File to be stored at your site */
  }
```

That will help you even if your font is not installed at your clients computer.

Hope it'll help you. cheers :)!

Comment: Still it is not recognizing.. :(

Comment: Does Your Computer have That font installed?

Comment: I don't understand why this answer was downvoted. It's a legitimate solution! +1

Comment: I think it's rather a suggestion, since for what we know from the question this could be just one of several possible solutions

Comment: No, My computer don't have. I am making it for client. it is not necessary, users who will access my site, should have Avenir Next font. Then what is solution, other than i must have Avenir next on my local.

Comment: @user3095179 Edited My Answer. Hope it'll be helpful now.

Comment: Thank you very much.. It worked in this way. :)

Comment: @user3095179 I'm glad that i could help you.