# My font and text size class doesn't work even though I copy and pasted the code

Tags: html, css

On my website, I have a class to change font and text size named `class='q'`. the class will not work even though I copy and pasted this from the home page as It is menu bar for all pages. All other classes work but not this one, Why?

```css
th.q {
 font-family: avenir;
 font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<BODY>
  <TABLE class='a' border='0' width='100%'>
 <TR height='20%'>
  <TH class='q'><a class="hover">About</a></TH>
  <TH class='q'><a>Products</a></TH>
  <TH class='q'><a>Pricing</a></TH>
  <TH class='q'><a>Contact</a></TH>
 </TR>
  </TABLE>
```

Comment: What's not working? The `font-size` is working perfectly, and for the font family you need to have a [`@font-face`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23754655/css-not-recognizing-avenir-next-as-my-font-family) of that font.

Comment: Welcome! Unfortunately the snippet seems to work fine, so it's probably something else causing this on your live website. Things that come to mind: 1. Old version of the CSS file is cached, 2. There is a more specific selector (for instance `tr th.q` would override `th.q`). In either case, you can use `inspect element` (right click the `th` in the browser) or otherwise check using the developer tools (F12) which CSS styles are applied, and which ones are overridden by others.

Comment: have you tried a hard refresh (ctrl + f5) to force the stylesheet to update - browsers can cache the stylesheet so a soft refresh will not reload it

Comment: I have a menu bar with links, the class should make the links have the font Avenir and be much larger than default but the text just takes its default font and shape.

Comment: Developer tools isnt showing all of the code. (sorry if I messed up, Im new and have never needed to use developer tools

Comment: You probably have a rule in your stylesheet targeting those links directly, that has a higher _specificity_. You can try to use the selector `th.q a` first, but if that doesn’t work, you will need to figure out where the currently applied styles are coming from first, and dev tools are the easiest way to do that.

Comment: these links and a small hover animation are the only things on the page, I just started coding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Referring to [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52600256/9029328):)

Unfortunately, giving multiple elements the same `id` invalidates your HTML. If the `#font` selector was enough to fix the problem, you should be able to give the `<table>` an `id` instead and select its `<th>` descendants:

```css
#navigation th {
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<TABLE id='navigation' class='a' border='0' width='100%'>
  <TR height='20%'>
    <TH><a class="hover">About</a></TH>
    <TH><a>Products</a></TH>
    <TH><a>Pricing</a></TH>
    <TH><a>Contact</a></TH>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
```

Also, the `border`, `width`, and `height` attributes should be in CSS, not HTML:

```css
#navigation th {
  font-size: 25px;
}
#navigation {
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
}
#navigation tr {
  height: 20%;
}
```

```html
<TABLE id='navigation' class='a'>
  <TR>
    <TH><a class="hover">About</a></TH>
    <TH><a>Products</a></TH>
    <TH><a>Pricing</a></TH>
    <TH><a>Contact</a></TH>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
```

Of course, you [shouldn't be using tables for layout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/83073/9029328), anyway.

Comment: Thanks, I just started with HTML and CSS about a month ago and I was taught at the start with decrepit code.

Comment: The problem somehow fixed itself on its own, this thread is now closed.

Answer (score 0):

Since nothing else works I have used Ids to fix it.

HTML

```
<BODY>
<TABLE  class='a' border='0' width='100%'>
    <TR height='20%'>
        <TH id='font'><a class="hover">About</a></TH>
        <TH id='font'><a>Products</a></TH>
        <TH id='font'><a>Pricing</a></TH>
        <TH id='font'><a>Contact</a></TH>
    </TR>
</TABLE>
```

CSS

```
#font {
font-family: avenir;
 font-size: 25px;
}
```